Can't access jenkins web interface in vultr
I am usign vultr vps with cloudpanel and ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I install jenkins and it's running but i can't access Jenkins web interface.
I have edited jenkins config by sudo systemctl edit jenkins and added these lines-
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=9090"
Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0"

Outpu of sudo ufw status-
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9090/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

I enabled 9090 port for both ipv4 and ipv6 from cloudpanel Firewall too.
Output of sudo netstat -tuln | grep 9090-
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN

I can't access it by serveripaddress:9090 it's unreachable.

Your problem has nothing to do with jenkins. If you start nginx on the same port you will have exactly same issue.
